# Создание компонентов JFrame в отдельных классах.

Tags: java, swing

Интересует такой вопрос: создаю в одном классе `JFrame`, в другом, к примеру, `JMenuBar`.
Также создаю переменную этого класса в классе с `JFrame`, но меню-бар не появляется.
Вот и интересно, можно ли так делать? Нужно ли? Просто, так удобнее редактировать компоненты, когда это необходимо. Грубо говоря выглядит всё это вот так:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
      private MyMenuBar menuBar;
       public MyFrame(){
      // описываем класс
    }
    menuBar = new MyMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
}

public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar{
       public MyMenuBar(){
       // описываем класс
  }
}
```

Comment: разберись до конца принцип работы и построения классов, библиотек и тд в яве, ты должен понимать, что все в яве - объекты, которые можно переопределять, другое дело, что не всегда это нужно делать. Отвечаю на вопросы, делать - можно, здесь такое делать - не нужно, если ты не собираешься писать свой менюБар, в этом случае только усложнишь код

Comment: то есть, получается, что все нужные компонетны и их listener`ы, лучше писать в классе MyFrame?

Comment: да, MyFrame - будет как контейнер, хранить listener`ы, а уже их обработку, если она сложная - можно лучше выводить в отдельные классы

Comment: благодарю! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menuBar = new MyMenuBar();
setJMenuBar(mymenubar);
```

найди 10 отличий

Comment: очепятка, бывает... но не в этом дело...